# Is there any way to install a VPN PPTP (not OpenVPN) Server on a NAS with FunPlug?

Tags: networking, vpn, nas, pptp

I have a [**CH3SNAS**](http://nas-tweaks.net/30/conceptronic-ch3snas/) from Conceptronic with [**FunPlug**](http://dns323.kood.org/howto:fun_plug) installed to enhance its capabilities.
I would like to install a **VPN PPTP** server, but I only have found *OpenVPN* packages for **FunPlug**.
Does somebody knows about a solution?

EDIT: My kernel is:

```
Linux CH3SNAS 2.6.12.6-arm1 #47 Mon Nov 30 12:06:02 CST 2009 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

Comment: PoPToP requires a kernel MPPE module to work.  So you'll have to install your own kernel on this with an MPPE module built for it.  Then you'll probably have to compile PoPToP and possibly things like `l2tpd` and such.  OpenVPN will be a lot easier to get working on this.

Comment: According to http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/redhat-howto.phtml, it seems that only 2.6.15-rc1 and below require MPPE to be specifically added. Mine is right now **2.6.12.6-arm1** (edited original post to include this info), so, if there is a chance to update the kernel, maybe PoPToP could solve it. Thanks, @ultrasawblade.